# DataGridView's column header on high DPI loses scaling

Tags: c#, winforms, highdpi

I have a simple Form with 2 DataGridViews:

[image]

They share the same column headers for illustration purposes.

The bottom one has a slight configuration in the column header:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

This is how its source looks like:

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Json.Net" Version="1.0.33" />
    <PackageReference Include="MessagePack" Version="2.4.59" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="WinForms.DataVisualization" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.designer.cs:

```
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.dataGridView2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Column1,
            this.Column2,
            this.Column3});
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 33);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 25;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(422, 108);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            // 
            // Column2
            // 
            this.Column2.HeaderText = "Column2";
            this.Column2.Name = "Column2";
            // 
            // Column3
            // 
            this.Column3.HeaderText = "Column3";
            this.Column3.Name = "Column3";
            // 
            // dataGridView2
            // 
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
            dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
            this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView2.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1,
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2,
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3});
            this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 179);
            this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
            this.dataGridView2.RowTemplate.Height = 25;
            this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(422, 108);
            this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1
            // 
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.HeaderText = "Column1";
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1";
            // 
            // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2
            // 
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.HeaderText = "Column2";
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2";
            // 
            // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3
            // 
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.HeaderText = "Column3";
            this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 15);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(128, 15);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.label1.Text = "Standard DataGridView";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 161);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(186, 15);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label2.Text = "DataGridView with custom header";
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(446, 299);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column2;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column3;
        private DataGridView dataGridView2;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2;
        private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn3;
        private Label label1;
        private Label label2;
    }
}
```

At 100% scaled displays, they both look great:

[image]

However, with a 2 display setup, being displayA 100% and displayB 250%: application started on displayA (100%), and moved to displayB (250%):

[image]

I wish to emphasize the column header's height and font here. In the upper grid, it's perfect, while the bottom one stays at the 100% scaled font.

If I remove the Font configuration from the bottom one, it scales perfectly too, just as the upper one.

How could I change font on the grid while preserve the high-DPI feature?

Slight addition: if I "pack" the grid into a panel, and change the font for the panel and removing the font setting from the header, it works between different-scaled displays.

### Update

Also the scrollbar looks very weird after moving to different monitor (compared to ListBox):

[image]

VS

[image]

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: which VS do you use? I'm on VS 2022.

Comment: VS 2022 (17.4.4) - .NET 7 (SDK 7.0.102)

Comment: And what scaling factor do you have on your displays?

Comment: 250 to 100. 250 is active by default. Then for this test I switch between 250 and 100.

Comment: You have two displays, right? And when you move from display (100) to display (250), you don't have this issue?

Comment: To make the text clearer and less confusing, I just test it on Laptop, with default scaling 250. Then change the scaling of laptop screen to 100, and see the result. In both scaling 100, 250 on laptop screen it worked fine.

Comment: I tried on two monitors as well. One 100, the other 200, and it works as expected.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit the question and include the project file content, program file content, and form1 file content. Shortest possible. Nothing else. Then tell the steps of reproduction on 1 or two monitors.

Comment: Did that. Also when there is data in the grid, the scrollbar looks awkward after moving to higher DPI. :(